# Handling express response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

node js:

```
res.json({url: "http://www.google.co.uk"});
```

Javascript:

```
http.open("post", server.authurl,true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form- 
urlencoded");
http.send(parameters);
console.log(JSON.parse(http.response.body).url
```

Returns syntax error, not sure how to fix this and access the url correctly

```
console.log(JSON.parse(http.response).url)
```

Returns unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: Can you elaborate what you have tried ?

Comment: In your "Javascript:" code (side note - they're **both** JavaScript), what is `http.response`? Where do you get it from? Separately, whenever you're asking about an error **say what the error actually is** (the complete, verbatim error, using copy and paste).

Comment: can you please put the code for JS part

Comment: is `http` an instance of `XMLHttpRequest` ?

Comment: @0.sh Yes it is

Comment: try to wrap JSON.parse on a try catch block and see if you get the url is logged out in the console. `console.log(JSON.parse(http.response).url)`

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is async so `response` is not available immediatelly after send. You need to move parsing code to say readystatechange event listener.